# Most Frequent of every N Elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, performance, frequency, qsort

I have a large array A of size [0, 8388608] of "relatively small" integers A[i] = [0, 131072] and I want to find the most frequently occurring element of every N=32 elements.

What would be faster,

A. Create an associative array B of size 131072, iterate through 32 elements, increment B[A[i]], then iterate through B, find the largest value, reset all elements in B to 0, repeat |A|/32 times.

B. qsort every 32 elements, find the largest range where A[i] == A[i-1] (and thus the most frequent element), repeat |A|/32 times.

(EDIT) C. Something else.

Comment: I'm leaning towards B. It also has the benefit of being independent of the size of the elements in A.

Comment: I think for this kind of thing you should go with the easiest one to write and change it later if it is a bottleneck. You need to benchmark  both of them to come to a conclusion.

Comment: With A you don't take advantage of the fact that 32 << 131072. You easily create an auxiliary array B which is fast to fill (increment B[A[i]]), but iterating through B to find the largest value will be expensive. I'd use an auxiliary structure to analyze just the 32 elements with _actual_ activity. Note that 32*32 = 1024 is still smaller than 131072.

Comment: a better approach be have the frequent data on dictionary o structure and update it when changes add, remove item and when you populate you array. Because populate add and delete is inevitable

Comment: Please rename the approaches.  Doe 'A' mean the first approach, or does 'A' mean the first array?

Comment: What happens when there is more than one solution? I would personally implement a stack of a 2 member struct tracking value and count. But the hash table is a very good idea. It's much harder to implement a hash than a stack in C though...

Comment: By "every 32 elements", do you mean the blocks 0-31, 32-63, etc. or 0-31, 1-32, 2-33, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An improvement over the first approach is possible.  There is no need to iterate through B.  And it can be an array of size 131072

Every time you increment `B[A[i]]`, look at the new value in that cell.  Then, have a global `highest_frequency_found_far`.  This start at zero, but after every increment the new value should be compared with this global.  If it's higher, then the global is replaced.

You could also have a global `value_that_was_associated_with_the_highest_count`

```
for each block of 32 members of A ... {
    size_t B [131072] = {0,0,...};
    size_t highest_frequency_found_so_far = 0;
    int value_associated_with_that = 0;
    for(a : A) { // where A just means the current 32-element sub-block
        const int new_frequency = ++B[a];
        if (new_frequency > highest_frequency_found_so_far) {
            highest_frequency_found_so_far = new_frequency;
            value_associated_with_that = a;
        }
    }
    // now, 'value_associated_with_that' is the most frequent element

    // Thanks to @AkiSuihkonen for pointing out a really simple way to reset B each time.
    // B is big, instead of zeroing each element explicitly, just do this loop to undo
    // the ++B[a] from earlier:
    for(a : A) { --B[a]; }
}
```

Comment: (Withdrawn, see @AkiSuihkonen below). On second thoughts, wiping all the elements of B might be expensive.  You might also want to record an 'age' with each element of B, which records what 'iteration' it was used with.  Then, if the algorithm finds a non-zero value from a previous iteration, then it knows it should zero it first.  This allows `B` to hold some 'stale' values.

Comment: Very well spotted. This solves the issue I pointed out with [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934468/most-frequent-of-every-n-elements-in-c#comment29666152_19934468).

Comment: You can simply wipe only 32 elements of B every time, but on second though too, the timestamp sounds quite effective.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You can wipe those 32 elements (provided you took note of them somehow), or alternatively, just use a completely different instance of B at each cycle.

Answer (score 2):

what about a btree?
You only need a max of 32 nodes and can declare them up front.